# Vue test utils for Vue3 : document is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vite

I try to bootstrap a simple app based on the following `Vue3`, `Vite`, `Vitest`

I also installed the vue 3 compatible version of [vue test utils](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/) to test vue components.

I have an error trying to replicate the basic example in the docs :

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { expect, test } from 'vitest'


// The component to test
const MessageComponent = {
  template: "<p>{{ msg }}</p>",
  props: ["msg"],
};

test("displays message", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(MessageComponent, {
    props: {
      msg: "Hello world",
    },
  });

  // Assert the rendered text of the component
  expect(wrapper.text()).toContain("Hello world");
});
```

```
 FAIL  src/tests/hello-world.test.ts > displays message
ReferenceError: document is not defined
 ❯ Proxy.mount node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js:7840:14
    7838|     addToDoNotStubComponents(component);
    7839|     registerStub({ source: originalComponent, stub: component });
    7840|     var el = document.createElement('div');
       |              ^
    7841|     if (options === null || options === void 0 ? void 0 : options.attachTo) {
    7842|         var to = void 0;
Re-running tests... [ src/tests/hello-world.test.ts ]
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "vite-vue3-poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "build": "vite build",
    "coverage": "vitest --coverage",
    "dev": "vite",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.2.25",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-alpha.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/cli-service": "5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "@vuetify/vite-plugin": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.7.2",
    "vitest": "^0.1.23",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.5",
    "vuetify-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vuetify from "@vuetify/vite-plugin";

import path from "path";
/// <reference types="vitest" />

// Configure Vitest (https://vitest.dev/config)

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    /* for example, use global to avoid globals imports (describe, test, expect): */
    // globals: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),

    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
  ],
  define: { "process.env": {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The problem is specific to testing framework you're using, vitest, not anything else. You're not in a good situation when using low-profile libs that don't have extensive support from the community. Since it seems to use Jest internally, this is likely solved from Jest side by enforcing Jest's `jsdom` environment.

Comment: Thx. This helped me finding a way (see below)

Answer (score 27):

Finally fixed it by manually installing `jsdom` and declaring it in `vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  test: {

    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
...
}
```

Comment: this works as well in a separate `vitest.config.ts` file. It might be possible then to add the file to your tsconfig.config.json

Answer (score 10):

Like others have pointed out, you need to set `environment: 'jsdom'` in `vitest.config.ts`. Alternatively, you could set `environment: 'happy-dom'`.

In the [example provided by the Vitest documentation](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/blob/main/examples/vue/vitest.config.ts), they used to use `happy-dom` instead of `jsdom`. From what I gather, `happy-dom` is a faster alternative to `jsdom`. I'm using `happy-dom` in my project, and I'm happy with it! :)

EDIT: I changed my wording to reflect the fact that the Vitest example used to use `happy-dom`. As of this writing, it uses `jsdom`.

Comment: Seems like they use `jsdom` now

Comment: Thanks, I changed the wording of my answer to reflect that they now use `jsdom`.

Answer (score 5):

This config helped me

Your `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import type { UserConfig as VitestUserConfigInterface } from "vitest/config"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

const vitestConfig: VitestUserConfigInterface = {
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  test: vitestConfig.test,
})
```

Comment: Yes - searching all over, and this solved it for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

No need to install `jsdom` manually. By setting `environment: "jsdom"` in the `test` property, Vitest automatically asks you if you want to install it.