# Unable to run Vue component tests with Vitest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I have a project configured as follows:

- Vue version: Vue 3
- Dev server: Webpack
- Testing utils: Vitest, Vue Test Utils

I'm able to write and run tests for simple JavaScript functions, but when I try doing the same for my components, I get the following error:

```
src/build/PartSelector.test.js [ src/build/PartSelector.test.js ]
Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
 ❯ formatError node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44062:46
 ❯ TransformContext.error node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44058:19
 ❯ TransformContext.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:41784:22
 ❯ Object.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44352:30
 ❯ loadAndTransform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:55026:29
```

I tried installing the plugin mentioned in the error message via `npm install "@vitejs/plugin-vue"` (without doing anything else), but that did not resolve the error.

Is there a way to resolve this error without having to switch over to Vite? Perhaps there's some additional config required after installing vite-plugin-vue that I don't know about?

Also, here is my `vitest.config.ts`, if that helps:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Installing the plugin is not enough; it also needs to be included in `defineConfig()` inside your config (which in my case is vitest.config.ts).

Solution: run `npm install "@vitejs/plugin-vue"`, and then edit vitest.config.ts to include the plugin (see below).

```
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"; // Import the plugin here

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
    globals: true,
  },
  plugins: [vue()], // Include it in your array of plugins here
});
```

Note that I also needed to set my `environment` variable inside `defineConfig()`. If you don't do this, you'll run into a different type of error later on telling you that "document is not defined". More information on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769062/vue-test-utils-for-vue3-document-is-not-defined).

Comment: Reading documentation is vital. Installing a different package than instructed in the error message, and not following the installation instructions for the package does lead to problems. Installing something doesn’t just mean “run npm install”, the usage is described clearly on the page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-vue

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, appreciate the subtle RTFM/reminder that documentation is important, but do keep in mind that I'm still new to frontend development. What may seem crystal clear to you might seem unclear or ambiguous to me. E.g. the link you posted begins with a snippet of vite.config.js, without any explanation as to what I'm looking at. Furthermore, I don't have a vite.config.ts, nor does that snippet reference defineConfig(), which adds to the confusion for someone in my position.